# Conjugate locus and local diffeomorphism problem in do Carmo's book.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading DoCarmo's book, Riemannian Geometry and i don't understand something. At page 149 first lemma [image]

My question is why $\text{exp}_p$ is local diffeomorphism?

Comment: It’s because it’s derivative is bijective

Comment: Oooo yes! Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

For $p\in M$ identify $T_{0}T_{p}M$ with $T_{p}M$  then :

$d(\exp_{p})_{0}(X_{p})=\frac{d}{dt}_{t=0}(\exp_{p}(tX_{p}))=X_{p}$  , $X_{p}\in T_{p}M$ .

the rest concluded by inverse function theorem.

Comment: This proves that $\text{exp}_p$ is diffeo on a neighbourhood of the origin. The lemma is more stronger because it asserts that $\text{exp}_p$ is local diffeo i. e. At every vector, not necessarily the origin, there is a neighborhood of that vector on which $\text{exp}_p$ is diffeo. A property of conjugate locus is that its dimension is equal to the dimension of $\text{ker} (d\text{exp}_p) $

Comment: For details, you can check in do Carmo's book at page 117, prop 3.5

Comment: The lemma is for complete riemannian manifold with negative sectional curvature , try to write down exponential map for 2-sphere at point (0,0,1) and vector with norm $\pi$ .